# how to get access token in python

Tags: python, api, rest, token

I want to make a rest api call and get access token and that access token will be there for 30 min. Again i need to refresh that token.

I am not getting how to get the access token, tried numerous code snippets.

Sample access token will be as below:
KkcwAIyUm6XGbGUA0wejna6_8kk3Zuo66BigYo3gAGI.

URL used in post man to get access token manually:
[https://xxx.xxx.com/restapi/vc/authentication/sessions/login?user.login=s_user&user.password=xxx]

Then i need to use this access token in below URL to fetch data:
[https://xxx.xxx.com/restapi/vc/messages/id/879997?restapi.session_key=kEf-mTzu6Xnsa5HQKt8ml-9Wc-HX3wHLlphB2oQkrxE.&restapi.response_format=json]

Can anyone help with python code for this

Code i am trying for getting access token:

```
    import requests
import json

with requests.Session() as session:
    req = requests.get(r'https://xx.xx.com/restapi/vc/authentication/sessions/login?user.login=s_user&user.password=xxxx')

print(req.content)
```

Output:
b'\n  F0JQfxkxxwl-O9-cQKtJhdrNRKJg3ENLd_SckmBIqU0.\n\n'

Code working for hard coding access token from post man:

```
for m in data_list:
    response = requests.get("https://xxx.xx.com/restapi/vc/messages/id/"+m+"?restapi.session_key=kEf-mTzu6Xnsa5HQKt8ml-9Wc-HX3wHLlphB2oQkrxE.&restapi.response_format=json")
    data = response.json()
    cleaned_text=cleanhtml(data['response']['message']['body']['$'])
    body_list.append(cleaned_text)
    #print(cleaned_text)
    #print ('---------BODY ENDS HERE--------')
    tz_subject = data['response']['message']['subject']['$']
```

When i hard code the access token that i got from post man i am able to fetch results using below code , but i am not getting how to generate access token in python and then use it, refresh it when i expires

Thanks you

Comment: Show the code you have so far

Comment: Don't put it in the comments but edit your question and format it properly as code

Comment: @MichaelButscher i have added code in question thank you

Comment: The token data is probably in the `req` variable of the first snippet (which is actually a response). I don't see a need for a POST request here, GET should do. Usually data is in JSON form which can be decoded in a similar way as in the second snippet. Details how the token is saved in the JSON should be given by provider of the REST API.

Comment: @MichaelButscher - you are right thank you its working now , i have edited the first snippet with working code to get access token this will expire every 30 min how i can regenerate and use it through code

Comment: Precise way to regenerate it should be documented by the API provider

Comment: Unfortunately no such document is provided - i need to find a way to keep checking if it expired then refresh token and use like this

Comment: REST isn't standardized enough to know this without additional docs. I guess that the login call from the first snippet must be repeated to receive a new token.

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok thank you for help, one last question:     
`res=req.json()` is not working `x=req.text` is working but giving ouput like this - how to extarct access token from there `<response status="success">
  <value type="string">jqUb-QG7n3lZp494Gm8lRH9-9iz0xm2WxR_XHXQ4LFE.</value>
</response>`

Comment: This is XML, use an XML parser, e.g. `xml.etree.ElementTree` from standard library

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok will try that thank you

Comment: @MichaelButscher how can i green tick your comment as answer ?

Comment: I have written an answer. Comments can't be accepted as answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token data is probably in the `req` variable of the first snippet (which is actually a response).

Usually the response data is in JSON format which can be decoded in a similar way as in the second snippet. In case of an XML format there are several parsers available, e.g. `xml.etree.ElementTree` from the Python standard library.

Details how the token is saved in the data and how to regenerate a token should be given by the provider of the REST API.